# .xib file is not using arc, despite my build settings saying use auto reference counting

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

When I control drag from interface builder to my .h and generate an IBOutlet property, it is automatically making it "retain", and adding delloc to the .m...  Why is this happening and how can I turn it off?

Comment: what version of Xcode did you use?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening and how can I turn it off?

It sounds like it's happening because you're using an older version of Xcode. I just tried it in Xcode 4.6.2 and it created a `weak` property and no `-dealloc`. If you're using something earlier than Xcode 4.6.2, it's time to update.

Comment: No.. I am on 4.6.3 (4h1503)